# Button with a ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a a button with a ng-click that is not firing. Below is the controller and  button html. Help - why is it not working?

This is my controller

```
    angular.module('app').controller('MarvelController', MarvelController);
    // use to make HTTP requests


    MarvelController.$inject = [
    "$http"
    ];
    var character = 0;


    function MarvelController($http){
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.update);

        self.character = character;
        self.glenn = 24;
        console.log(self.glenn);
        self.chris = function(){
            console.log("chris");
        }
```

this is the button that is not firing:

```
<button ng-click="chris()">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your function on $scope it will work. Or you can use the controller as syntax. e.g.

```
<div ng-controller="MarvelController as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.chris()">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var self = this;
  self.chris = function()
  {
    console.log("chris");
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.chris()">button</button>
  </body>

</html>
```